# jQuery DatePicker issue when multiple element of same class name are used in web page

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

Following is my Spring mvc2 code

```
<c:forEach var="trackRecord"  varStatus = "number" items="${contractDetails.trackRecordEntries}" >
  <tr class="tafont">
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" id = "installmentNo" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].installmentNo"/></td>

      <td class="varcar"><form:input cssClass="recievedDate" id = "recievedDate" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].recievedDate"/></td>  
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

it creates a html file which have multiple  elements with the same className. Whenever i click on any element date picker popsup and works properly. but the changes made through date picker are reflected only in the first element which has class name 'recievedDate'. So for any element's date picker changes are made only in first element.

Here is the date picker code

```
 $( '.recievedDate').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          changeMonth:true,
          changeYear:true,
          maxDate: '0',
        });
```

Any Solutions ???

Comment: ids are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 1):

You will need to handle more than one so try

```
$('.receivedDate').each(function(){
  $(this).datepicker({ 
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth:true,
      changeYear:true,
      maxDate: '0',
    });
});
```

Comment: This type of code is used many many times by our company, so I guess you have some other error.  Looking at you code I see 'cssClass' but not 'class' and also as mentioned before 'id' should be unique.  Please sort out your html.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by removing id attribute

```
<td class="varcar"><form:input cssClass="recievedDate"  path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].recievedDate"/></td>
```

would like to know the reason for same  :)

Answer (score 0):

When your gets executed then your code will have more than one id `recievedDate`
So it will not work.Give different id for datepicker and in the jquery use this way

```
$( '.recievedDate','recievedDate1','recievedDate2').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          changeMonth:true,
          changeYear:true,
          maxDate: '0',
        });
```

Comment: The number of such elements are not fixed. So how can i give them id to be used with jQuery  ??

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I am not sure whether the other answer will work or not but you can get the ids dynamically so put it in an array and retrive the same inside$( '.recievedDate')

Comment: @AbhishekSingh as i told you there can not be multiple ids